# app request is not working

Tags: .net, facebook-graph-api

I am using graph api apprequests url to create app request to one of my friends in        friends list. But that request is getting posted into my profile only.

```
www.graph.facebook.com/125xxx5287/apprequests
```

inputs are

```
"message" : "Hi"   
       "to" : {
    "name": "xxx",
    "id": "19034532452334"
  }
```

This is app request is getting posted into my profile instead of my friends profile.
What is the problem here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending Facebook apprequests without dialog](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6076597/sending-facebook-apprequests-without-dialog)

Answer (score 0):

What documentation are you using? that's not a valid API call.

Apps can add an [app-> user request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/) to any of their existing users by `POST`ing to `/USER_ID/apprequests`, but what you've done there is try to programmatically create a user->user request. The [only valid parameters](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#apprequests) when creating such a request are `message` and `data`. The recipient user ID is already specified in the path.

This is not possible, you must use the [Requests Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) for such a request.